# Searching for a variable (=previously defined pattern) using grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'd like to create a bash script.
Therefore, I defined a variable

```
pattern1=Today,\ 15:46
```

I had to add a \ before the space " " because otherwise I get the error "command not found"

Now, I used this command to search the pattern in out.txt:

```
grep -c '$pattern1' out.txt
```

Here grep doesn't find anything.

However, when I type in

```
grep -c 'Today, 15:46' out.txt
```

I get a result.

Also with the following code, I don't get any result:

```
define pattern2=15:46
grep -c '$pattern2$ out.txt
```

Where is the mistake?
Can grep not look for a previously defined pattern? Is there a trick to look for the pattern anyway?

I'd be grateful for every help!

Kind regards,
X3nion

Comment: Single quotes prevent variable expansion. Use double quotes instead: `grep -c "$pattern"`

Comment: Related: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373), also elsewhere: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: The assignment `pattern1=Today,\ 15:46` is fine, but you could also use quotes here, it might be clearer: `pattern1="Today, 15:46"`

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked out!